# Rollup 'is not exported' error prevents me from making a build

Tags: javascript, rollupjs

I'm a novice at bundling tools and give a start with Rollup because we use it in corp. But when I want to build, it greets me with the following error:

```
yarn run v1.22.17
$ rimraf dist && tsc && rollup -c rollup.config.js

./out-tsc/unit/index.js → dist...
(!) Unresolved dependencies
https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#warning-treating-module-as-external-dependency
fs (imported by out-tsc\unit\cached-git-repo.js)
child_process (imported by node_modules\simple-git\esm\index.js)
[!] Error: 'exists' is not exported by node_modules\@kwsites\file-exists\dist\index.js, imported by node_modules\simple-git\esm\index.js
https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#error-name-is-not-exported-by-module
node_modules\simple-git\esm\index.js (13:7)
11:   for (var prop in b || (b = {}))
12:     if (__hasOwnProp.call(b, prop))
13:       __defNormalProp(a, prop, b[prop]);
           ^
14:   if (__getOwnPropSymbols)
15:     for (var prop of __getOwnPropSymbols(b)) {
Error: 'exists' is not exported by node_modules\@kwsites\file-exists\dist\index.js, imported by node_modules\simple-git\esm\index.js
    at error (C:\Users\ibrah\WebstormProjects\versioned-projects-source-manager\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\rollup.js:160:30)
    at Module.error (C:\Users\ibrah\WebstormProjects\versioned-projects-source-manager\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\rollup.js:12436:16)
    at Module.traceVariable (C:\Users\ibrah\WebstormProjects\versioned-projects-source-manager\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\rollup.js:12797:29)
    at ModuleScope.findVariable (C:\Users\ibrah\WebstormProjects\versioned-projects-source-manager\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\rollup.js:11419:39)     
    at FunctionScope.findVariable (C:\Users\ibrah\WebstormProjects\versioned-projects-source-manager\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\rollup.js:6395:38)    
    at ChildScope.findVariable (C:\Users\ibrah\WebstormProjects\versioned-projects-source-manager\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\rollup.js:6395:38)       
    at Identifier.bind (C:\Users\ibrah\WebstormProjects\versioned-projects-source-manager\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\rollup.js:7684:40)
    at CallExpression.bind (C:\Users\ibrah\WebstormProjects\versioned-projects-source-manager\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\rollup.js:5284:23)
    at CallExpression.bind (C:\Users\ibrah\WebstormProjects\versioned-projects-source-manager\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\rollup.js:8866:15)
    at ReturnStatement.bind (C:\Users\ibrah\WebstormProjects\versioned-projects-source-manager\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\rollup.js:5284:23)

error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

I'm on verge of going nuts. Because the website Rollup redirects me has nothing about it contrarily to what it claims to have. Could you help me to fix this issue?
I don't think anything is wrong with config files, nevertheless, I shared them in the following if you want to check.

```
# package.json
{
  "name": "versioned-projects-source-manager",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "rimraf dist && tsc && rollup -c rollup.config.js",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "glob": "^7.2.0",
    "simple-git": "^3.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@open-wc/building-rollup": "^2.0.1",
    "@types/jest": "^27.4.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.10.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.10.2",
    "deepmerge": "^4.2.2",
    "eslint": "^8.8.0",
    "ini": "^2.0.0",
    "jest": "^27.4.7",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "rollup": "^2.67.3",
    "ts-jest": "^27.1.3",
    "typescript": "^4.5.5"
  }
}
```

```
# rollup.config.js
import merge from 'deepmerge';
import { createBasicConfig } from '@open-wc/building-rollup';

const baseConfig = createBasicConfig();

export default merge(baseConfig, {
  input: './out-tsc/unit/index.js',
  output: {
    dir: 'dist',
  }
});
```

```
# tsconfig.json
{
  "include": [
    "./src/**/*.ts",
    "./src/**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "./node_modules/**"
  ],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2018",
    /* Set the JavaScript language version for emitted JavaScript and include compatible library declarations. */
    "module": "esnext",
    /* Specify what module code is generated. */
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    /* Specify how TypeScript looks up a file from a given module specifier. */
    "lib": [
      "es2017"
    ],
    "sourceMap": true,
    /* Create source map files for emitted JavaScript files. */
    "outDir": "./out-tsc",
    /* Specify an output folder for all emitted files. */
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    /* Emit additional JavaScript to ease support for importing CommonJS modules. This enables `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` for type compatibility. */
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    /* Ensure that casing is correct in imports. */
    "strict": true,
    /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
    "skipLibCheck": true
    /* Skip type checking all .d.ts files. */
  }
}
```